# Can a single man buy a used mattress from a single woman?

Tags: halacha, women, transactions, sleep

Can a single man buy a used mattress from a single woman? Is there any halachic (e.g. concerning modesty, I know that there are specific prohibitions for single men in halacha)  issues that I am not aware of?

Comment: Hi mordechia! Please [edit] your question to clarify why you think this might be a problem. Without such information, it's hard to understand why you'd have this question and hence it's hard for someone to be sure to address your concerns. Generally, buying and selling things is permitted.

Comment: Are you asking for a problem of bad thinking?

Comment: There are things not prohibited that you canprohibit to yourself if you feel not good with this

Answer (score 2):

Rabbi Azriel Chaim Goldfein Zatzal told me once that we do not prohibit things that are not mentioned that they are prohibited. To the best of my knowledge there is no such prohibition.

Comment: Seems more like a comment (unless you went through Gemara/Medrashim/Shulchan Aruch/Shut and can say that *no one* prohibited it

Comment: While there may not be any particular prohibition regarding mattress sales, it may involve some broader prohibition.

Comment: Perhaps we can say that for  s msshkon,  following Rabbi  Shim'on who  doresh taams dekra.  An almsna ashirs whoch has memashken a mattress,  no  problem but  chachamim prohibots.  If I remember there is a magid mishne.  May be a good source to connect the question with  gemarot

Comment: I'd say it's a good answer...what other answer would you prefer? The question is not clear anyway.